# Spring cron scheduler for every 59 seconds do double run

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need my task to run every 59 seconds from 9am to 6pm, I mean not at 59 seconds of every minute, but 59 seconds after the previous run ends. So i set such a cron to my sheduler `*/59 * 9-21 * * *`

There is a code

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/59 * 9-21 * * *")
public void schedule() {
    try {
        log.info("Scheduler starts!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error was caught in scheduler", e);
    }
}
```

And that's what I see in log:

```
2022-02-09 16:01:00.002 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:01:59.002 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:02:00.001 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:02:59.002 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:03:00.002 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:03:59.001 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:04:00.001 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:04:59.002 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:05:00.001 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:05:59.002 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:06:00.001 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:06:59.002 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
2022-02-09 16:07:00.001 | spring-vault-ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1 | INFO  | com.app.MyScheduler             [ / ] -       Scheduler starts!
```

Why does it work in such way and duplicate run at 59 and 00 seconds of each minute? Is my cron wrong?

UPD:
I'm using grails 4.0.1

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible with a cron expression. Is `fixedRate = 59` an option?

Comment: but is it possible to set range from 9am to 6pm in fixedRate? As I now it isn't, that's why I chose cron

Comment: Your cron expression is ok. You can test it with:     var expression = CronExpression.parse("*/59 * 9-21 * * *");
    var result = expression.next(LocalDateTime.now());
    System.out.println(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the scheduler.

With the following test code You will see that 2 schedules occur when the current time is in the second 59 on in second 00.

```
  Set<String> x = new HashSet<>();
    List<LocalDateTime> y = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {

      var expression = CronExpression.parse("*/59 * 9-21 * * *");
      final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
      y.add(now);
      x.add(expression.next(now).toString());
      System.out.println(x);
      Thread.sleep(500);

      if (x.size() > 2){
        break;
      }
    }

    System.out.println(x);
```

I obtained 3 results

> [2022-02-09T15:58:59, 2022-02-09T15:59:59, 2022-02-09T15:59]

For the following dates:

[image]

[image]

I've tested this with Spring Boot version 2.6.3.

Comment: So, this bug relates to Spring? Is there a way to fix it? Btw, I'm using grails 4.0.1

Comment: And what dependency should I add to use CronExpression.parse? I don't have CronExpression class in my project

Comment: I guess you have to open a bug in Spring issue tracker. The dependency:
spring-context (5.3.15).